# On check of chekboxes display another checkboxes

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

What I want that there is a basic primary technology chekboxes. Now When I cheked on that chekboxes according to checkbox cheked it's feature technology display with the checkbox control.

This is My primary Technology chckbox code:-

```
<div class="form-group">
              <label for="location" class="col-sm-4 control-label">TECHNOLOGIES</label><span style="color:red;margin-left:-307px;">*</span> 
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <?php if(@$aTechCount>0){
                    foreach( $aTechnology as $oType ){ 
                    ?>
                      <li style="list-style-type:none;"><input type="checkbox" name="tech[]" onClick="return Validate_Check();" value="<?php echo @$oType->technology_id; ?>" id="tech"><?php echo  strtoupper(@$oType->technology_name); } }?></li>
              <span id="check_error" style="color:red;font-weight:bold;"></span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: pass some value in javascript and use ajax to get about data of particular techo.

Comment: @KimJones this is not a place where anyone write code for anyone , you should try yourself first . then if you face any problem we are here to help you .

Comment: **[Check this out](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/2txy33x9/)**

Comment: @GuruprasadRao your code is helpfull but my secondary tech. display from table nad for that I call the ajax but when I uncheck It's not hide secondary technology. I paste the ajax call code and method also paste.

Comment: @KimJones As mentioned in below answer by Sainik Kumar you check whether `checkbox` is `checked` or `unchecked` using if-else, if its `unchecked` then use this `$('.subtypes').find('#'+pritech).toggleClass('hide');` in else part.

Comment: Ya that is alrady done by me. But U mention another div that is hide div in that <div id="php" class="hide"> u mention id="php" But my id is dynamic so how I mention dynamic id.

Comment: Thanks For Solution. My Problem solved.

Comment: One issue face that if i give class="hide" and cheked any technology it's not display any sub tehcnology. but when i change the class name hide to data_hide and write this line in else part $('.subtypes').find('#'+pritech).toggleClass('hide'); than also it's not hide the subtechnoloy. Can suggest where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with attaching an event to your checkboxes.

```
 $('checkbox').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        //show your subcategory checkboxes for this checkbox
    }
    else{
    //hide your subcategory checkboxes for this checkbox
    }  
});
```